# How to make size of apk file smaller created in cordova

Tags: html, cordova, apk

I create android .apk app using html,css,javascript in cordova 2.9.0 
i use only my html,css,and javascript without any API , in assert>www folder.
But every time the created apk size greater than 1mb. I want to delete some files such that it don't effect the created app. Please point out the file which is not requred.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is use cordova > 3.0.

Wirh cordova 2.x, all system plugins were installed by default.

With cordova 3.x you add only plugins you need, so the app is smaller ans requires less permissions.